# Unable to preview the uploaded image [rest api]

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, base64, codeigniter-restserver

I'm trying to do uploading from my Ionic App to the codeigniter Rest Server but the image cannot be previewed when I open it. I'm referring to this tutorial to do the uploading from the app side https://www.djamware.com/post/5ae9c9ca80aca714d19d5b9f/ionic-3-angular-5-and-cordova-base64-image-upload-example

**Here is my code from Ionic App:**

```
img = { "data":"", "user_id":"" };

getPhoto() {
  let options = {
    maximumImagesCount: 1
  };
  this.imagePicker.getPictures(options).then((results)=>{
    for(let i=0; i < results.length; i++){
      this.imgPreview = results[i];
      this.base64.encodeFile(results[i]).then((base64File: string) => {
        this.img.data = base64File;
        this.status = true;
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
  });
}

// Function to submit the data to rest api
UploadImages(){
  this.restProvider.postAction('my-rest-api-url', this.img).then((data)=>{
      this.msg = JSON.stringify(data['img']);
      this.restProvider.triggerToastMsg('Images uploaded to gallery.');
  });
}
```

**From my Rest Server in Codeigniter side :**

```
function uploadImage_post(){
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $data = json_decode($postdata);

    if(!empty($data)){
        $img = $data->data;
        $imgStr = substr($img, strpos($img, "base64,") + 7);
        $imgData = base64_decode($imgStr);
        $imgName = uniqid().'.jpg';

        $imgData = array(
            'author_id'   => $data->user_id,
            'file_src'    => $imgName,
        );

        $this->Gallery_model->createMyGallery($imgData);
        $root = dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
        $dir = $root.'/my-dir-goes-here';
        file_put_contents($dir.$imgName, $imgData);

        $this->response([
            'http_status_code' => REST_Controller::HTTP_OK,
            'status' => true,
            'statusMsg' => 'OK'
        ], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }
}
```

From what you can see on the api side, the `$data->data` will resulting the encoded base64 which is something like `data:image/*;charset=utf-8;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZjRgA....................`

So, in order to remove the `data:image/*;charset=utf-8;base64,` I use the `substr()` to get the data after it `/9j/4AAQSkZjRgA....................` then only I decode it back. I manage to upload it to my server directory but when I tried to open the image, it doesn't open it. It will appear something like image corrupted. The image filesize also just small which is **19 bytes**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look closely to your rest server side. You've been assigning `$imgData` value twice which is replacing the value of the decoded base64 to an array value. That is why your code on the line `file_put_contents($dir.$imgName, $imgData);` unable to get the image that you're trying to save.

You should place your code in this order :

```
$img = $data->data;
$imgStr = substr($img, strpos($img, "base64,") + 7);
$imgData = base64_decode($imgStr);
$imgName = uniqid().'.jpg';

$root = dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
$dir = $root.'/my-dir-goes-here';
file_put_contents($dir.$imgName, $imgData);

$imgData = array(
    'author_id'   => $data->user_id,
    'file_src'    => $imgName,
);

$this->Gallery_model->createMyGallery($imgData);
```

Comment: Yeah I not even realized that. Thanks